# MySQL 100% CPU Usage Reading from a 500.000 Rows table

Tags: mysql, mariadb, myisam

I'm using MariaDB 10.1

My config is the follow

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql

key_buffer_size = 2G
read_buffer_size = 2G

symbolic-links=0
skip-name-resolve=1
query_cache_limit       = 4M
query_cache_size        = 256M

expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

max_connections  = 8096
back_log = 4096
open_files_limit = 20240
innodb_open_files = 20240

table_open_cache = 8096
table_definition_cache = 8096

tmp_table_size = 2G
max_heap_table_size = 2G

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 10
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
performance_schema = 0
innodb-file-per-table = 1
innodb_table_locks = 0

thread_cache_size = 8096
thread_handling = pool-of-threads
thread_pool_size = 20
thread_pool_idle_timeout = 20
thread_pool_max_threads = 2048

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

I have one table MYISAM (DESCRIBE)

```
MariaDB [ip2proxy]> DESCRIBE ip2proxy_px2;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ip_from      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| ip_to        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| proxy_type   | varchar(3)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| country_code | char(2)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| country_name | varchar(64)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [ip2proxy]> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ip2proxy_px2;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|   482450 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

We do more than 8.000 reads / second against that database to search for IPs.
The MySQL Is going to 100% in all Cores (12 Threads) and then it is crashing.

We want all the requests to be executed without any delays.

The query we execute is:

```
SELECT proxy_type FROM `ip2proxy_px2` WHERE {IPLONG} BETWEEN ip_from AND ip_to LIMIT 1;
```

Any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: See my answer on a similar question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33133/slow-query-gets-even-slower-after-indexing/33139#33139

Comment: Forgot to mention, that i already use LIMIT 1;

Comment: Check the 2nd part of the answer, regarding non-overlapping ranges. If know that your IP ranges do not overlap, you can use the faster query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much RAM?  Many of the entries in my.cnf look "too big" unless you have a lot of RAM.

Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

InnoDB would be faster because the data is clustered with the `PRIMARY KEY`.

What is happening...  Each run of that query is scanning half the index, starting with IPLONG=ip_from and going to the end of the index.  Meanwhile, it is reaching over to the data (since it is separate in MyISAM) for the other columns.

Are the ip_from..ip_to pairs non-overlapping?  If so, you could check one row, then quit.  If they are overlapping, there is no hope.

The `LIMIT 1` will not be sufficient without `ORDER BY ip_from`.

You realize that the table cannot handle IPv6?

Make sure that `country_code` is `CHARACTER SET ascii`.  Don't include `country_name` in the same table; build a lookup (normalization) table mapping `country_code` to `country_name`.

Comment: Yes i have plenty of RAM. I changed to InnoDB and seems a lot better now. I also removed the country_code and country_name since i don't need them ( it is the database from ip2location).

However i have one strange Problem. Can someone tell me why when i run the SAME query(above) multiple times, i get different results? Is something i'm missing? Of course we are talking about the same IP.

Comment: Did you add the `ORDER BY` that I suggested?  Without it, the engine is at liberty to deliver any rows that meet the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: with the ORDER BY THE CPU is 100% all the times. Any idea?

Comment: It may sound strange, but the net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1 in systsctl.conf fixed my cpu load with 8000 requests / second and now the results are ok ( Some connections to mysql before were failing thats why i was getting different results). Thanks for everything